# Split the sheet in multiple sheet in same workbook

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import openpyxl as xl
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import csv
import xlwings as xw
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
import fnmatch
from openpyxl.utils.formulas import FORMULAE
import datetime
import sys
import numpy as np
```

#this piece of code is working but splitting it as the separate workbook like ( "sill_split_1.csv","sill_split_2.csv"---so on, but i wanted all in one workbook as a separate sheet removing the original one.

```
 for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if filename.endswith('.csv') and  "sill" in filename and "vulns" in filename:
            for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=500000)):
                chunk.to_csv('sill_split_{}.csv'.format(i), index=False)
                print("Done")
```

Comment: CSV can not have sheets. Excel have sheets. Try writing the data using `to_excel` function in a same file. Make sure you use correct write mode.

Comment: ok let me try by using it